# SublimeText error

Tags: sublimetext2, jslint

I keep getting this error when I try to save a file in sublime text 2 after installing a few packages:

```
[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd:  [u'node', u'C:\\Users\\johndoe\\AppData\\Roaming\\Sublime Text 2\\Packages/JSLint/linter.js', u'--predef', u"['angular', 'document', '$', '_', 'JQuery', 'FB']", u'--sloppy', u'--indent', u'2', u'--node', u'--nomen', u'--vars', u'--plusplus', u'--stupid', u'--todo', u'V:\\editFormDisableColumns.js']]
[dir:  V:\]
[path: C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\]
[Finished]
```

Comment: What packages did you install, and what settings did you change? Do you have node.js installed on your system?

Comment: I don't have NodeJs installed. I installed Alignment, Bracket Highlighter, Emmet, JsFormat, JSLint, LiveReload, Package Control, Prefixr, Sidebar, JSLint is there twice for some reason, SublimeCodeIntel and SublimeLinter

Answer (score 0):

If you check out the [README for JSLint](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/JSLint) you'll notice that it requires [Node.js](http://www.nodejs.org) to be installed and in your PATH (this option is enabled by default in the Windows installer). Once you've done that, restart Sublime and you should be all set.

On a larger note, [SublimeLinter](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter) includes `jslint` built in, so the two packages are essentially redundant. Visit the [Package Control website](https://sublime.wbond.net), look up your various packages, and read all about them so you don't end up with redundancies or conflicts.